# При нажатии на checkbox первый раз действие выполняется нормально, но второе действие срабатывает только по двойному клику

Tags: php

Вот код, что может быть не так?

```
echo "<form action='' name='switch' method='POST'>";

if ($value === true) $value='0';
else if ($value === false) $value='1';

if ($value === '0') $checked = 'checked';
else if ($value === '1') $checked= '';

        echo "<input class='toggle-checkbox' name=".$device_id."_".$i." value = $value type='checkbox' $checked onClick='this.form.submit()'>";

        if (isset($_POST[$device_id."_".$i])) {
            switch ($_POST[$device_id."_".$i]) {
            case '0':

                if ($value === '0') $values = true;
                else if ($value === '1') $values = false;

                $payload = [ 'code' => $code , 'value' => $values ];
                .....   
                
                break;
            case '1':

                if ($value === '0') $values = true;
                else if ($value === '1') $values = false;

                $payload = ['code' => $code , 'value' => $values];
                ......
                
                break;
    }
}
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: чую проблема в js

Comment: из js кода у меня только это  onClick='this.form.submit()' передает данные без кнопки submit

Comment: А что подразумевается под "первое действие" и "второе действие"?

Comment: первый клик по чекбоксу действие срабатывает (грубо говоря Вкл.), а чтобы выключить (второе действие) срабатывает только после двойного клика по чукбоксу

Comment: Либо помогите с php кодом, есть переключатель on/off идет проверка на включен или выключен, тем самым подставляя значение volume в checkbox и в зависимости от состояния on/off мне нужно передать значение true или false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что значение чекбокса не передаётся, если он не checked.
Поэтому добавляем ещё один инпут, который будет (или не будет) перекрываться чекбоксом:

```
echo "<form action='' name='switch' method='POST'>";

$value = intval($_POST[$device_id . "_" . $i]);

$checked = $value == 1 ? 'checked' : '';

echo "<input type='hidden' name=" . $device_id . "_" . $i . " value = 0>";
echo "<input class='toggle-checkbox' name=" . $device_id . "_" . $i . " value = 1 type='checkbox' $checked onClick='this.form.submit()'>";

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $payload = ['code' => $code, 'value' => $value === 1];
}

echo "</form>";
```

Ну и маленько упростил код.

Comment: Спасибо значение с intval выдает ошибку, а при нажатии на чекбокс убирается из другого чекбокса выделение. Так на странице множество чекбоксов

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, сделал так. Спасибо за подсказку Виктору Кареву (скрытый checkbox) избавился от двойного клика

```
echo "<form method='POST'>";
        if ($value === false) {
            echo "<label class='toggle'><input class='toggle-checkbox' name=".$device_id."_".$i." type='checkbox' value='0' onchange='this.form.submit()'><div class='toggle-switch'></div><span class='toggle-label'>".$code."</span></label>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name=" . $device_id . "_" . $i . " value ='1' checked>";
            echo "<label class='toggle'><input class='toggle-checkbox' name=".$device_id."_".$i." type='checkbox' value='1' checked onchange='this.form.submit()'><div class='toggle-switch'></div><span class='toggle-label'>".$code."</span></label>";
        }
        echo "</form>";
   
        if (isset($_POST[$device_id."_".$i])) {
            switch ($_POST[$device_id."_".$i]) {
            case '0':
                $values = true;
                $payload = [ 'code' => $code , 'value' => $values ];
                $tuya->devices( $token )->post_commands( $device_id , [ 'commands' => [ $payload ] ] ); 
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";     
                break;
            case '1':
                $values = false;
                $payload = ['code' => $code , 'value' => $values];
                $tuya->devices( $token )->post_commands( $device_id , [ 'commands' => [ $payload ] ] );
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
                break;
        }
} echo "</form>";
```